# Using "new" with initializer_list does not assign string values, while int values work

Tags: c++, stl, dynamic-memory-allocation, initializer-list

It works when I create a variable with `std::initializer_list<std::string>`:

```
auto a = std::initializer_list<std::string>{"1", "2", "3", "4"};
```

[image]

But when I create a variable with **a pointer** to `std::initializer_list<std::string>`, the values of the pointer are empty:

```
auto b = new std::initializer_list<std::string>{"1", "2", "3", "4"};
```

[image]

I tried with integer values and both cases work (`std::initializer_list<int>{1, 2, 3, 4}` and `new std::initializer_list<int>{1, 2, 3, 4}`).

Comment: not sure what the "needs details or clarity" are about, the question seems pretty clear except for misuse of "static"

Comment: @M.M I just removed the "static", thanks

Comment: It would be good to verify the contents with a real program -- sometimes debugger displays can be faulty (especially if the authors of the debugger didn't consider this situation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the standard (C++17) it says, referring to the array of `const std::string` which backs the `initializer_list`:

> The array has the same lifetime as any other temporary object, except that initializing an initializer-list object from the array extends the lifetime of the array exactly like binding a reference to a temporary.

In your code the dynamically-allocated initializer-list object is initialized by the array, so this text applies.

The lifetime extension rules for binding a reference to a temporary **inside a new-initializer** are: (C++17 [class.temporary]/6.3)

> A temporary bound to a reference in a *new-initializer* persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the *new-initializer*. [Example:
>
> ```
> struct S { int mi; const std::pair<int,int>& mp; };
> S a { 1, {2,3} };
> S* p = new S{ 1, {2,3} }; // Creates dangling reference
> ```

So it seems the backing array is destroyed at the end of the line containing the `new`  , so trying to inspect it after that would cause undefined behaviour (meaning you may or may not see what you expect).

Answer (score -1):

So I wrote a full example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void print(std::initializer_list<std::string> &il)
{
    for (auto &s: il) std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main( void ) {
    auto a = std::initializer_list<std::string>{"1", "2", "3", "4"};
    auto b = new std::initializer_list<std::string>{"5", "6", "7", "8"};

    print (a);
    print (*b);
}
```

And the compiler told me what was wrong:

```
$ clang++ std=c++17 so.cpp
so.cpp:12:49: warning: array backing the allocated initializer list will be destroyed at the end of the full-expression
      [-Wdangling-initializer-list]
        auto b = new std::initializer_list<std::string>{"5", "6", "7", "8"};
                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

Comment: vs19 produced no warning for me